# Почему очень долго отрабатывает данный скрипт?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("/var/log/mylog/2019_01_26.log", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
          $array = preg_split("/(T| |,)/", $buffer);
         echo $array[0] . ' ip: ' . $array[2] . ' what: ' . $array[3] . ' статус: ' . $array[4] . ' событие: ' . $array[5] . ' ' . $array[6] . $array[7] . $array[8] . '<br />';
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }

?>
```

Почему данный скрипт очень долго отрабатывает? Браузер даже предлагает завершить выполнение на странице. Файл занимает всего 511 КБ. 
P.S.: Выполнение операции происходит до пяти минут.

Comment: Мы не знаем, почему он медленно работает

Comment: Файловые операции всегда самые медленные, только если у вас не SSD. Подгружайте в память (в какую-нибудь переменную) содержимое Log файла с интервалом например 30 секунд. А для вывода на PHP берите из памяти, т.к. в один момент времени эту страницу могут грузить 10 тысяч человек - и хана вашему сайту с его диском.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

Comment: При длине строки в 1КБ (а скорее всего сильно меньше), тут 511 строк. Окучить рекуляркой 511 строк - это не самая быстрая операция. Возможно дело в этом.

Comment: Браузер предлагает завершить выполнение js. Возможно дело в клиенте а не в сервере. Дёрните запрос напрямую, загляните во вкладку сеть, в инструментах разработчика в браузере. Проведите замеры времени выполнения (xdebug умеет).

Comment: Сколько здесь теоретиков собралось.

Comment: долго то это сколько? 2 секунды, минута, час? какое конкретное время то? Как именно выглядят ваши строки лога, и что вы хотите из  них получить.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, до пяти минут.

Comment: Замерьте время выполнения вот этой строки `$array = preg_split("/(T| |,)/", $buffer);`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, как?

Comment: time(). в РНР есть такая функция. возвращает время в секундах. Можно заметить время до, время после, и вывести разницу. Вот только разница составит 0 секунд.

Comment: `preg_split` с выводом закомментируйте, узнаете сколько чтение занимает, а сколько нарезка строк.

Answer (score -1):

Такой код не отрабатывает быстрее? Если нет то скорее всего дело в preg_split

```
$handle = file("/var/log/mylog/2019_01_26.log");
foreach((array)$handle as $buffer){
    $array = preg_split("/(T| |,)/", $buffer);
    echo $array[0] . ' ip: ' . $array[2] . ' what: ' . $array[3] . ' статус: ' . $array[4] . ' событие: ' . $array[5] . ' ' . $array[6] . $array[7] . $array[8] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Свои догадки следует высказывать в комментариях, а не в виде ответа на вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев это мой ответ на вопрос - вероятно долго отрабатывает из-за fopen/fgets. Точный ответ дать не возможно не имея файла который парсят и машины в конфигурации которой работает скрипт. Кроме того в комментариях нет возможности разместить форматированный код.